Upgrading my calipers
I am thinking of upgrading the calipers on my Cannondale Topstone 4 2024 as the stock ones are rather crap.
Can I keep the stock discs or do they need changing also ?
I am considering TRP Spyre-C Mechanical Disc Brake Calipers.
Any advice welcome.
The bike was ordered online and had full set up by the shop. The brakes are only 1 month old but they are very screechy and don't have the best stopping power. I live in a mountainous area so stopping is paramount. It came with a Microshift Advent x group set, Promax calipers.

What does the bike currently have? All discs should be  compatible, the current one can normally stay.

How much effort have you put into getting the setup right. Are the pads contaminated and need replacing?  Organic pads would help you have sintered Pad adjustment, cable housing etc. Just replacing calipers is unlikely to make a worthwhile difference *that said, some can be so finicky to adjust right that replacement with something that is easy to setup and get right is the best option).

Hi, the bile was set up by the shop and delivered.

Different disc brakes use pads that might be of a different material. Per this answer, wipe the disc rotors down with isopropyl alcohol, then go bed the brakes in. The store should have done that on the present set, it just involves going out and doing a few hard stops. Disc rotors aren't paired to disc calipers in the same way that you usually need to use a brake caliper with its lever, or a rear derailleur with the corresponding shifter.
It's also possible that fault with the brakes lies in low-quality housing. If you have the wherewithal, you could consider changing the housing, but this involves feeding the housing through the bike. You won't have the tools, and if you go this route, you'd need to pay a bike store.
